# Nonsingular matrix that can't undergo LU decomposition without permutation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I've been trying to think of this. My teacher said there could be a nonsingular matrix with all nonzero entries that can't be decomposed without a permutation.

Comment: That works but it has zero entries.

Comment: Why not just take a non-identity permutation matrix?

Answer (score 0):

An LU factorization of a nonsingular matrix without permutations exists if and only if all leading principal submatrices are nonsingular.

We can construct a matrix for which the permutations are necessary by picking one which violates this condition. This is impossible for $1\times 1$ and $2\times 2$ matrices (either there would be a zero element or the whole matrix would be singular).

So let's try a $3\times 3$ one. For example,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
     1  &   1  &   1 \\
     1  &   1  &   2 \\
     1  &   2  &   3 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The leading principal submatrices are
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
     1  
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\begin{bmatrix}
     1  &   1  \\
     1  &   1  \\
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\begin{bmatrix}
     1  &   1  &   1 \\
     1  &   1  &   2 \\
     1  &   2  &   3 
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where the second one is singular. Hence the LU factorization is impossible without permuting. It is easy to see that by performing the first step of the elimination, which leaves a zero entry in the $(2,2)$ position, which cannot be used as a pivot.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find a way to do this without degenerate rows